# unable to install turtle in python using either anaconda prompt or command prompt?

Tags: python

`python -m pip install turtle`

Using this command to install turtle, but it is throwing an error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install turtle
Collecting turtle
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f0/21a42e9e424d24bdd0e509d5ed3c7dfb8f47d962d9c044dba903b0b4a26f/turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\vaibh\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\vaibh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7hujbb79\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\vaibh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7hujbb79\\turtle\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7hujbb79\turtle\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7hujbb79\turtle\setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax incompatible for Python2 of turtle, you can download [turtle](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f0/21a42e9e424d24bdd0e509d5ed3c7dfb8f47d962d9c044dba903b0b4a26f/turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz) to your local PC,

then unzip it, modify the `setup.py` line 40 to `except (ValueError, ve):`

then try to install it `pip install -e turtle-0.0.2`.

Comment: it does not have some attributes like bgcolor, color etc

Comment: it does not have some attributes like bgcolor, color etc